# Visual Studio 2017 (v15.9.14) says "Deploy failed" when attempting to debug sample Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to deploy the example app in this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/first-app/?pivots=win-vs2017

However, I'm unable to get the debugger to work for it.  I followed all the steps precisely but nothing seems to work.

Here's the log output:

> Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Initialization finished
>   Xamarin|Information|0|Xamarin - 4.12.3.83-d15-9+23fa80172
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.Shell.BuildProjectSettings|Information|0|Settings successfully saved.
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Initialization finished
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage|Warning|0|Initializing Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Initialization finished
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.XamarinIOSPackage|Warning|0|Initializing Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.XamarinIOSPackage.
>   Xamarin.Inspector|Information|0|Inspector extension loaded
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyFlavoredProject|Error|0|System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidFlavoredProject.CreateDeployCommand(IProgressReport progress) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\ProjectSystem\MonoAndroidFlavoredProject.cs:line 672
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyFlavoredProject.StartDeploy(IProgressReport progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\FlavorProject\TastyFlavoredProject.cs:line 532
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyFlavoredProject|Error|0|Project is not deployable.
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj'
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyFlavoredProject|Error|0|System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidFlavoredProject.CreateDeployCommand(IProgressReport progress) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\ProjectSystem\MonoAndroidFlavoredProject.cs:line 672
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyFlavoredProject.StartDeploy(IProgressReport progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\FlavorProject\TastyFlavoredProject.cs:line 532
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyFlavoredProject|Error|0|Project is not deployable.
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyFlavoredProject|Error|0|System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidFlavoredProject.CreateDeployCommand(IProgressReport progress) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\ProjectSystem\MonoAndroidFlavoredProject.cs:line 672
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyFlavoredProject.StartDeploy(IProgressReport progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in E:\A_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\FlavorProject\TastyFlavoredProject.cs:line 532
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyFlavoredProject|Error|0|Project is not deployable.

I'm seeing a lot of "No such interface supported" errors but I don't know what they mean.  Any ideas?

Comment: The logs mention Android as well as iOS. From your tags I gather you want to deploy to Android, is that correct? Did you select Android as your startup project in Visual Studio?

Comment: It's Xamarin.Forms which means it's supposed to be platform-agnostic.  VS creates separate projects for Android and iOS when you select this.  The problem occurs when I try to debug the Android project.

Comment: I agree with @ThomasHilbert, make sure you set the android project as _start up project_ by right clicking on it, also make sure the android project is deployable by right clicking on solution, selecting _Configuration manager_ and then enabling Deploy check box for android.

Comment: `'C:\dev\repos\BirdieApp\src\BirdieMobileApp\BirdieMobileApp.Android\BirdieMobileApp.Android.csproj' System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. ` Sounds like an issue with an object Visual Studio uses. Please report a problem using the `Help` menu inside Visual Studio.

Comment: So then there's not even a workaround for this??  I can't afford to wait the however many weeks or months it'll take for them to release a fix.  I really need to be able to deploy this.

Comment: It works in general, I've been working with Xamarin.Forms for years now on both Android and iOS. It must have to do something with your environment. Try reinstalling stuff, try a different system if need be, but there must be something wrong on your end.

Comment: What are you even trying to do btw? You say you want to deploy the solution, but attach a debugger? As far as I understand it, to debug the app you usually simply start the Android project in debug mode and Visual Studio will install the app on your device and attach the debugger. The "Deploy" function is usually meant to create a Release build and package it into an apk, which can then be distributed - you don't use that for debugging. So what is it you want, debug or deploy?

Comment: Starting the app in debug mode returns the same error; it looks like debug automatically includes deployment. The deploy box is already checked in Configuration Manager for the .Android project and setting it as the startup project had no effect.